# Envers - Field modification in a @ManyToOne mapped Entity, does not trigger update in the AuditedJoinColumn

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-envers

Consider these classes:

```
@Audited
@Entity
public class Child
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private Father father;

    private String name;
}


@Audited
@Entity
public class Father
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private Set<Child> children;

    public void addChild(Child child)
    {
        if (null == this.children)
            this.children = new HashSet<>();

        this.children.add(child);
    }

    private String name;
}
```

When a child and a father are created, mapping is done correctly.  After the relationship is made, updating the name of the child will not be updated in the AuditedJoinColumn.

Therefore after this test:

```
import org.hibernate.envers.AuditReader;
import org.hibernate.envers.AuditReaderFactory;
import org.hibernate.envers.query.AuditEntity;
import org.hibernate.envers.query.AuditQuery;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class BasicTest
{
    private static final EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("EnversTest");

    private Long fatherId;
    private Long childId;

    @Before
    public void setup()
    {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        try
        {
            em.getTransaction().begin();

            Father father = new Father();
            father.setName("Dad");

            Child child = new Child();
            child.setName("Sam");
            child.setFather(father);

            father.addChild(child);

            em.persist(child);
            em.persist(father);
            em.getTransaction().commit();

            this.fatherId = father.getId();
            this.childId = child.getId();

            /////// Change child's name ///////

            em.getTransaction().begin();
            child.setName("John");
            em.persist(child);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        finally
        {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void validateChildForAllRevisions()
    {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        try
        {
            { // assert there are 2 revision of child
                List<Object[]> changes = getAllRevisions(Child.class, childId, em);
                assertNotNull(changes);
                assertEquals(2, changes.size());
                assertEquals("Sam", ((Child)changes.get(0)[0]).getName());
                assertEquals("John", ((Child)changes.get(1)[0]).getName());
            }

            { // assert there is 1 revision of father
                List<Object[]> changes = getAllRevisions(Father.class, fatherId, em);
                assertNotNull(changes);
                assertEquals(1, changes.size());

                // make sure latest father has a child named John
                Father lastRevOfFather = (Father)changes.get(0)[0];
                assertNotNull(lastRevOfFather);
                assertNotNull(lastRevOfFather.getChildren());
                assertEquals(1, lastRevOfFather.getChildren().size());

                for (Child auditedChild : lastRevOfFather.getChildren())
                    assertEquals("John", auditedChild.getName());
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void validateChildNameAtSpecificRevision()
    {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        try
        {
            Date time = new Date();

            List<Object[]> changes = getLastRevision(Father.class, fatherId, em, time);
            assertNotNull(changes);
            assertEquals(1, changes.size());

            Father auditedFather = (Father)changes.get(0)[0];
            assertNotNull(auditedFather);
            assertNotNull(auditedFather.getChildren());
            assertEquals(1, auditedFather.getChildren().size());

            for (Child auditedChild : auditedFather.getChildren())
                assertEquals("John", auditedChild.getName());
        }
        finally
        {
            em.close();
        }
    }

    public List<Object[]> getAllRevisions(final Class clazz, final Long entityId, EntityManager em)
    {
        AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(em);

        AuditQuery query = reader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(clazz, false, false);
        query.add(AuditEntity.id().eq(entityId));

        return query.getResultList();
    }

    public List<Object[]> getLastRevision(final Class clazz, final Long entityId, EntityManager em, final Date time)
    {
        AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(em);
        Number rev = reader.getRevisionNumberForDate(time);

        AuditQuery query = reader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(clazz, false, false);

        query.add(AuditEntity.id().eq(entityId));
        query.add(AuditEntity.revisionNumber()
                             .maximize()
                             .add(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().le(rev))
                             .computeAggregationInInstanceContext());

        return query.getResultList();
    }

    @After
    public void cleanup()
    {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        try
        {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.remove(em.find(Father.class, fatherId));
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        finally
        {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Child name comparison assertion fails:
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[John]> but was:<[Sam]>

So far, the only way I see to force the re-mapping is to also change something in the father.

I'm hoping there's a better way to do this.

Comment: Can you extend the test so that it contains code that fails?

Comment: Hi Adam,  full unit-test is now added.  Thank you for your time!

Comment: So you have two revisions, can you check what revision number you get in the getAudit method? To simplify and try to debug, maybe try reading the Father at revision `1` and `2` (or whatever the numbers are), and compare then - does it still break?

Comment: (reading the Father at revision 2 should get children at revision 2, even if the father was only modified in rev 1)

Comment: I agree, at revision 2, Father (rev 1) should return Child (rev 2).  However they are both at rev 1.  I believe this is because, after the child's name change, table Father_Child_AUD still contains just a single column, mapping:  Rev 1, Father_id 1, Children_id 1 and REVTYPE 0.

Comment: Adam, I have expanded the unit-test to validate each revision of father and child likewise.  This shows that there are 2 revisions recoded correctly for a child, and 1 revision recorded correctly for a father.  However, there is only one mapping column connecting first revision of a father to a first revision of a child.

I am not sure if it is the case, but it feels like when a field modification on a Child occurs, the map is not traversed to update those tied to it through a Join.

If I were to change the name of the Father as well, only then the map gets updated.

Comment: I think things work as they should. When you try to read the *last revision* of the Father, it correctly points to the only revision present - revision 1. Father was not changed later. Now, if you would read Father at revision 2 (at which it was not modified, however you can still read the entity at that revision), you would see the Father pointing to the new Child.

Comment: I do read Father at revision 2 - it is the revision number that is obtained at time after all changes are made.   So a call "Number rev = reader.getRevisionNumberForDate(time);"  (when the DB is clear) returns number 2.

Comment: No, in `getLastRevision` you are looking for the biggest revision (`maximize`), where the entity with `entity` id changed - and that's revision 1. If, instead, you read data at revision `rev` (e.g. by adding an equal constraint on the revision number, instead of maximizing it), you'll get what you want.

Comment: You're absolutely correct Adam.  Switching to "AuditQuery query = reader.createQuery().forEntitiesAtRevision(Clazz.class, rev);" fixes all issues I had.  Thank you again!